# Data is not set by recycler Adapter?

Tags: android

```
public class InformationFragment extends Fragment
{

   @Override
   public void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_view, container,false);
      recList = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);


      LinearLayoutManager linearLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

      linearLM.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

      if (listitems.size() > 0 & recList != null) {

      }

      new NewsTask().execute();

      recList.setLayoutManager(linearLM);
      return rootView;
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   }

   public class NewsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String API_URL = "http://bubli.herokuapp.com/news.json";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(API_URL).build();

        Response response;

        String a[]=new String[3];
        try {
            response= client.newCall(request).execute();

             array = new JSONArray( response.body().string());

            for (int i=0; i<array.length();i++)
              {

              Pojo news_indi = new Pojo();


           news_indi.setUrl(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("url"));

                news_indi.setTitle(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                Log.i("Title",array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
              news_indi.setContent(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("content"));
              news_indi.setSource(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("source"));
              news_indi.setImage(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
              listitems.add(news_indi);



            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("zain", "Doing in background");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        listitems.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
 //           listitems.subList(0, 10).clear();
    }
   }

 }

public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Pojo> list;

Context con;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Pojo> data, Context con) {
    //this.data = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
   list=data;
    this.con = con;
}

@Override
public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    View itemView =  LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.information, viewGroup, false);
            CardViewHolder ch=new CardViewHolder(itemView);
    return ch;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder holder, int i) {



    Picasso.with(con).load(list.get(i).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

    holder.titleText.setText(list.get(i).getTitle());

    Log.i("Information",list.get(i).getTitle());

    holder.sourceText.setText(list.get(i).getSource());



        holder.contentText.setText(" ");

    final int x =i;

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(con, DetailNews.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", holder.titleText.getText().toString());

            intent.putExtra("content", list.get(x).getContent() );


          intent.putExtra("source",holder.sourceText.getText().toString());

            intent.putExtra("image", list.get(x).getImage());
            intent.putExtra("url", list.get(x).getUrl());
            con.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}

@Override

public int getItemCount() {

    return list.size();
}
}


public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public  int i;

InformationFragment infoobj =new InformationFragment();

private Context con;


public TextView titleText;
public TextView contentText;
public TextView sourceText;
public ImageView imageView;



public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {


    super(itemView);

    titleText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);


    sourceText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.source);


    contentText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);


    imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

}
}
```

Comment: You don't set the adapter for your `RecyclerView`..

Answer (score 1):

Your **PostExecute** method should looks like below:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MyRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(listitems, getActivity());
        recList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

You **did not set Adapter** on **RecyclerView**.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: bundle of thanx .. :)

Comment: @MuhammadShan, Can you please accept the answer if correct and it helped you.